# dataset for apriori algorithm not able to convert into csv

Tags: database, data-mining, apriori

I went to this site fimi.ua.ac.be/data/ and downloaded the retail data set.
I tried everything to convert it into .csv but I couldn't get the format of csv.
Can anyone help me to convert this retail data set file into csv?
Please help.Thanks.

Comment: CSV is underspecified. There are a 100 different CSV dialects. We cannot help you here beyond "separate your data with `,`".

Answer (score 0):

It's a space separated file. You have two options: 1) convert it to comma separated , or 2) set your csv opening tool to open a space separated file instead of a comma separated.

If you are on *nix (unix, linux etc.) system option 1) is easier. You can achieve that by using this command:
sed 's/ /,/g' retail.dat > CSV_Retail.dat

If you are on windows option 2) is easier and MS office excel sheet has an option of reading a file separted by spaces instead of comma (or using the space delimiter)